# Converting vector equation to a list of equations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Due to DSolve syntax, systems of differential equations have to be given as lists of equations and not as a vector equation (Unlike Solve, which accepts both).
So my simple question is how to convert a vector equation such as:

```
{f'[t],g'[t]}=={{a,b},{c,d}}.{f[t],g[t]}
```

To list of equations:

```
{f'[t]==a*f[t]+b*g[t],g'[t]==c*f[t]+d*g[t]}
```

I think I knew once the answer, but I can't find it now and I think it could benefit others as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using Thread:

```
Thread[{f'[t], g'[t]} == {{a, b}, {c, d}}.{f[t], g[t]}]
(* {f'[t] == a f[t] + b g[t], g'[t] == c f[t] + d g[t] *)
```

It takes the equality operator `==` and applies it to each item within a list with the same `Head`.

Comment: @Mike if you are going to expand old answers, please consider also adding documentation links to relevant functions and concepts.  For example, the word `Head` does not appear anywhere in the code, and that could leave someone guessing.

Answer (score 7):

The standard answer to this question is that which [Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4452339/421225) presented, 
i.e., using `Thread`.
However, I find that for use in `DSolve`, `NDSolve`, etc... the command [`LogicalExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogicalExpand.html) is better.

```
eqn = {f'[t], g'[t]} == {{a, b}, {c, d}}.{f[t], g[t]};

LogicalExpand[eqn]

(* f'[t] == a f[t] + b g[t] && g'[t] == c f[t] + d g[t] *)
```

It doesn't convert a vector equation to a list, but it is more useful since it automatically flattens out matrix/tensor equations and combinations of vector equations. 
For example, if you wanted to add initial conditions to the above differential equation, you'd use

```
init = {f[0], g[0]} == {f0, g0};

LogicalExpand[eqn && init]

(* f[0] == f0 && g[0] == g0 && 
  f'[t] == a f[t] + b g[t] && g'[t] == c f[t] + d g[t] *)
```

An example of a matrix equation is

```
mEqn = Array[a, {2, 2}] == Partition[Range[4], 2];
```

Using `Thread` here is awkward, you need to apply it multiple times and `Flatten` the result. Using `LogicalExpand` is easy

```
LogicalExpand[mEqn]

(* a[1, 1] == 1 && a[1, 2] == 2 && a[2, 1] == 3 && a[2, 2] == 4 *)
```